# How to connect css and js files to flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm stuck in my python project.
the project is about a book library.
I need to have 4 html pages (index,books,customers,loans).
in books,customers,loans I need to have CRUD.
the database should be in SQL.
when doing any CRUD operation (using javascript), the database should save.

I made some flask applications but I did not try to seperate the files (the project should be in seperated files).

here is my folder structure:

```
/main folder
    app.py
    /project
        __init.py__
        /core
            __init__.py
            views.py
            /static
                styles.css
                script.js
            /templates
                index.html
        /books
            __init__.py
            views.py
            models.py
            forms.py
            /static
                styles.css
                script.js
            /templates
                index.html
        /customers
            __init__.py
            views.py
            models.py
            forms.py
            /static
                styles.css
                script.js
            /templates
                index.html
        /loans
            __init__.py
            views.py
            models.py
            forms.py
            /static
                styles.css
                script.js
            /templates
                index.html
```

app.py (goes to *init*.py)

```
from project import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*init*.py (blueprints)

```
import os
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate


# DATABASE SETUP
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'supersecret' #to allow us to use forms, not safe for deployment
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)


# REGISTER BLUEPRINTS

from project.core.views import core
from project.books.views import books
from project.customers.views import customers
from project.loans.views import loans

app.register_blueprint(core)
app.register_blueprint(books)
app.register_blueprint(customers)
app.register_blueprint(loans)
```

core (project/core/views.py

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint

core = Blueprint('core', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

@core.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">

    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HOME </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

when I load the page I get 404 error for the css/js

```
"GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

also when I create a static folder in /project folder, the css WILL LOAD! BUT, I get 304 error

```
"GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

why is this happening? the path seems correct for the styles.css file.
also, how the templates folder is found and the static folder isn't? they basically in the same place?
in overall, this is how the folder structure should be like?

I tried using ChatGPT to help but it gave the same answer for folder path (when it was already they way it said)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a static in /project folder and clear the cache of the browser.

The HTTP 304 response indicates that the result is cached by the browser.

if you clear your browser's cache, you'll observe that Flask responds with a 200 status code on your subsequent request.

Comment: It didn't work
basically I changed the whole folder structure.
I removed the static and templates in each folder and made one static and one template folders inside the main project folder.

Answer (score 0):

From [Flask-Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/)

> By default the rightmost part of the path is where it is exposed on
> the web. This can be changed with the `static_url_path` argument.
> Because the folder is called `static` here it will be available at the
> `url_prefix` of the blueprint + `/static`.  If the blueprint has the
> prefix `/admin`, the static URL will be `/admin/static`.

Try calling your static path like

```
url_for('core.static', filename='styles.css')
```